# Samsung galaxy A5 USB Otg supported?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, usb-on-the-go

I have checked with few USB Otg checkers it said there are Apr are present in mobile. But i could not able to connect Pendrive. Many entry levels phones also have this feature. But this is recently launched metal body phone.  I really wondered why this feature is not present. Any way to enable this?